# PHP PDO - How do I update the Database with Radio button values which already contain the current database value?

Tags: php, html

Updated to be more relevant.

I'm fairly new to PHP as shown below. But I'm currently generating the database and storing the values in Radio buttons, I then want to if changed to be sending new values and updating the database, however I'm struggling to find any material on updating with PHP. There is more to the code as this is just a snippet of the relevant bits. All opening brackets do have the corresponding closes too.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select SID, ClassID,StudentName, Week_1, Week_2, Week_3, Week_4, Week_5, Week_6, Week_7, Week_8, Week_9, Week_10 FROM weekbyweek");

$stmt->bindColumn('SID', $SID);
$stmt->bindColumn('ClassID', $ClassID);
$stmt->bindColumn('StudentName', $StudentName);    
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_1', $week_1);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_2', $week_2);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_3', $week_3);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_4', $week_4); 
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_5', $week_5);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_6', $week_6);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_7', $week_7);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_8', $week_8);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_9', $week_9);
$stmt->bindColumn('Week_10', $week_10);

   $stmt->execute();

 print ("<form action='Table/Update2.php' method='post'><tr>");

            //print a cell
            print ("<td> $SID </td>");
            print ("<td> $ClassID </td>");
            print ("<td> $StudentName </td>");
    // print the radio buttons
            print ("<td> $week_1 <input type='radio' value='1' name=" . $name1 ." " . (($week_1 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' value='0' name=" . $name1 ." " . (($week_1 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_2 <input type='radio' name=" . $name2 ." " . (($week_2 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name2 ." " . (($week_2 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_3 <input type='radio' name=" . $name3 ." " . (($week_3 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name3 ." " . (($week_3 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_4 <input type='radio' name=" . $name4 ." " . (($week_4 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name4 ." " . (($week_4 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_5 <input type='radio' name=" . $name5 ." " . (($week_5 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name5 ." " . (($week_5 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_6 <input type='radio' name=" . $name6 ." " . (($week_6 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name6 ." " . (($week_6 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_7 <input type='radio' name=" . $name7 ." " . (($week_7 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name7 ." " . (($week_7 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_8 <input type='radio' name=" . $name8 ." " . (($week_8 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name8 ." " . (($week_8 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_9 <input type='radio' name=" . $name9 ." " . (($week_9 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name9 ." " . (($week_9 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_10 <input type='radio' name=" . $name10 ." " . (($week_10 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name10 ." " . (($week_10 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");

            //close row
            print ("</tr>");
            $ind++;  print ("</table>");
        print ("<input type='submit' name='submit' value='update' onclick='updateDB'/></form>");
```

The above successfully prints out the database values as 1's and 0's. However I'm struggling to update the new values to the database, as shown below.

```
function updateDB ($db) {

$week1 = ( isset($_POST['Week_1']) ? '1':'0' );
$week2 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name2 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week3 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name3 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week4 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name4 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week5 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name5 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week6 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name6 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week7 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name7 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week8 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name8 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week9 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name9 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week10 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name10 . "']) ? '1' : '0');

try { 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sqlQuery = "Update weekbyweek SET  Week_1=?, Week_2=?, Week_3=?, Week_4=?, Week_5=?, Week_6=?, Week_7=?, Week_8=?, Week_9=?, Week_10=?";
$statement->prepare($sqlQuery)->execute(['?','?','?', $name1, $name2, $name3,$name4,$name5,$name6, $name7, $name8,$name9,$name10]);



$statement = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute();
}
  }
        UpdateDB();
```

I don't know how to update values 100%, however I've managed to get to this... There seems to be limited reading on updating multiple values so any help or advice would be top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Ollie

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> isset

to check whether the radio button is checked/uncheck, because it 
was unchecked, the form wouldn't send any form data for the particular name.

For example to get the value of the radio button:-

```
$week1_value = ( isset($_POST['Week_1']) ? '1':'0' );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. How would I then go about posting the data into the database, I've updated the question to show the current issue.